# Problems running Dash in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, google-colaboratory, plotly-dash

I just copy and paste the first batch of code from :
https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started to my Jupyter notebook and this what I am getting:

**Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 124-434-522
Debugger PIN: 124-434-522
Debugger PIN: 124-434-522
Debugger PIN: 124-434-522
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: 1**

Any help will be more than appreciated.

**(Updated comment)**
I have aslo tried google colab. Unfortunately it doesn't work on it neither. this is what I am getting:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import dash
      2 import dash_core_components as dcc
      3 import dash_html_components as html
      4 
      5 external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'

**(Second update)**
I am running the same script in Atom. Unfortunately it doesn't seen to be working:
[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the tutorial you are looking for https://plot.ly/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/. As Alexander explained Dash is a web server. If you are just learning python and want to plot stuff with Jupyter, running a webserver is not what you need. Instead you have to install a plot library like `plotly` or my favorite `matplotlib`. To install it, you would run `! pip install plotly` from inside Jupyter. The tutorial will walk you through it.

Answer (score 1):

Your last picture shows that dash is working perfectly fine
Go to the URL that is indicated in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can not use debug=True with Jupyter Notebook. Change to False or else run the code from a code editor/IDE.